# Hosting error with Heroku (Node/Express/PostgreSQL)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku

I'm trying to host my backend with Heroku created in Node with Express/PostgresSQL/Bookshelf/Knex but I'm running into an error and this is the first time hosting something in node.

Full Heroku logs:

```
2016-12-31T20:31:29.069373+00:00 app[web.1]:     at loader (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
2016-12-31T20:31:29.069374+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
2016-12-31T20:31:29.069375+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2016-12-31T20:31:29.069375+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2016-12-31T20:31:29.069376+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
 2016-12-31T20:31:29.078379+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
2016-12-31T20:32:25.362589+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-12-31T20:32:25.362722+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-12-31T20:32:25.490163+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-12-31T20:32:25.503103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-31T20:34:22.986995+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-12-31T20:34:22.987007+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-12-31T20:34:22.808949+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user bradleycravens@gmail.com
2016-12-31T20:34:22.808949+00:00 app[api]: Deploy aabe7e2 by user bradleycravens@gmail.com
2016-12-31T20:34:23.154490+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-31T20:34:25.399465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-12-31T20:34:28.313447+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-31T20:34:28.313461+00:00 app[web.1]: > workouts_server@1.0.0 start /app
2016-12-31T20:34:28.313462+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon --watch src --exec babel-node -- src/index.js
2016-12-31T20:34:28.313463+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-31T20:34:28.674900+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] 1.11.0
2016-12-31T20:34:28.676312+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2016-12-31T20:34:28.676716+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching: /app/src/**/*
2016-12-31T20:34:28.677296+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `babel-node src/index.js`
2016-12-31T20:34:30.799714+00:00 app[web.1]: It's aliiive!
2016-12-31T20:34:31.191662+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-12-31T20:34:33.199781+00:00 app[web.1]: Unhandled rejection error: select "workouts".* from "workouts" where "user_id" = $1 - relation "workouts" does not exist
2016-12-31T20:34:33.199799+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.parseE (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:554:11)
2016-12-31T20:34:33.199800+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.parseMessage (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:381:17)
2016-12-31T20:34:33.199800+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:117:22)
2016-12-31T20:34:33.199801+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
2016-12-31T20:34:33.199802+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2016-12-31T20:34:33.199803+00:00 app[web.1]:     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
2016-12-31T20:34:33.199803+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
2016-12-31T20:34:33.199804+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)
2016-12-31T20:34:32.721170+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.parseMessage (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:381:17)
2016-12-31T20:34:32.721171+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:117:22)
2016-12-31T20:34:32.721173+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
2016-12-31T20:34:32.721153+00:00 app[web.1]: Unhandled rejection error: select "workouts".* from "workouts" where "user_id" = $1 - relation "workouts" does not exist
2016-12-31T20:34:32.721169+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.parseE (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:554:11)
2016-12-31T20:34:32.721174+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2016-12-31T20:34:32.721174+00:00 app[web.1]:     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
2016-12-31T20:34:32.721175+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
2016-12-31T20:34:32.721176+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)
2016-12-31T20:35:02.683518+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/workouts/1" host=i-workout.herokuapp.com request_id=fc21163c-5df0-43f0-9572-fa7b16d6c1ab fwd="216.40.82.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-12-31T20:35:03.191102+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/workouts/1" host=i-workout.herokuapp.com request_id=2ffe1393-8fce-4d88-8d14-b1b390037bc7 fwd="216.40.82.105" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-12-31T20:44:07.901256+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-12-31T20:44:07.901266+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-12-31T20:44:07.759224+00:00 app[api]: Release v15 created by user bradleycravens@gmail.com
2016-12-31T20:44:07.759224+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 5a9ad8c by user bradleycravens@gmail.com
2016-12-31T20:44:08.078676+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2016-12-31T20:44:08.079167+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-12-31T20:44:08.539241+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-12-31T20:44:08.703155+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-12-31T20:44:09.967148+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-12-31T20:44:12.242286+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-31T20:44:12.242298+00:00 app[web.1]: > workouts_server@1.0.0 start /app
2016-12-31T20:44:12.242298+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon --watch src --exec babel-node -- src/index.js
2016-12-31T20:44:12.242299+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-31T20:44:12.537954+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] 1.11.0
2016-12-31T20:44:12.539225+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2016-12-31T20:44:12.539611+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching: /app/src/**/*
2016-12-31T20:44:12.540118+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `babel-node src/index.js`
2016-12-31T20:44:14.323564+00:00 app[web.1]: It's aliiive!
2016-12-31T20:44:14.981609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574010+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/knex/src/client.js:210:25
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574012+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise._execute (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574013+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:481:18)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.573992+00:00 app[web.1]: Unhandled rejection Error: There is no pool defined on the current client
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574013+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Client.acquireConnection (/app/node_modules/knex/src/client.js:208:23)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574013+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Promise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574015+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:481:18)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574016+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Promise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574014+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/knex/src/runner.js:188:49
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574016+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/knex/src/runner.js:187:35
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574014+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise._execute (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574017+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:39:29)
 2016-12-31T20:44:16.574018+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Runner.ensureConnection (/app/node_modules/knex/src/runner.js:186:23)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574018+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Runner.run (/app/node_modules/knex/src/runner.js:27:31)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574018+00:00 app[web.1]:     at QueryBuilder.Target.then (/app/node_modules/knex/src/interface.js:22:45)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574017+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.574019+00:00 app[web.1]:     at QueryBuilder.tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025272+00:00 app[web.1]: Unhandled rejection Error: There is no pool defined on the current client
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025287+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/knex/src/client.js:210:25
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025288+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise._execute (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025289+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:481:18)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025289+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Promise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025290+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Client.acquireConnection (/app/node_modules/knex/src/client.js:208:23)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025291+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/knex/src/runner.js:188:49
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025292+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise._execute (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025292+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:481:18)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025293+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Promise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025293+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/knex/src/runner.js:187:35
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025294+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025295+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:39:29)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025296+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Runner.ensureConnection (/app/node_modules/knex/src/runner.js:186:23)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025296+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Runner.run (/app/node_modules/knex/src/runner.js:27:31)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025297+00:00 app[web.1]:     at QueryBuilder.Target.then (/app/node_modules/knex/src/interface.js:22:45)
2016-12-31T20:44:16.025298+00:00 app[web.1]:     at QueryBuilder.tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
2016-12-31T20:44:45.977575+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/workouts/1" host=i-workout.herokuapp.com request_id=89f31a97-e35f-4aaa-b16a-a9d669adf0bf fwd="216.40.82.105" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-12-31T20:44:46.569114+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/workouts/1" host=i-workout.herokuapp.com request_id=02919f3b-50ec-48aa-8dd9-6e5df0def5f4 fwd="216.40.82.105" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

github repo: https://github.com/bcravens/WorkoutsServer

Comment: It says that `sh: 1: nodemon: not found` meaning that nodemon is not being installed. That's at least of the problems, or the problem.

Comment: Okay, I ran an npm install --save on nodemon and babel and now I'm getting a Knex issue. I'll edit the original post and show my logs.

Comment: Is it trying to run locally? `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 `

Comment: Yeah I think so, `Running on localhost:8080`

Comment: I'm not sure what to switch when I want to host it. In index.js I have: `app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.listen(app.get("port"), function(){
  console.log("It's aliiive!");
});`

Comment: @BradleyCravens `app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function(){
  console.log("It's aliiive!");
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your app is not set up for production. Try changing your knexfile to work with production:

```
production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: process.env.HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_URL, // env var
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
}
```

and you bookshelf file to :

```
export default bookshelf(knex(knexConfig.production))
```

Comment: Do I replace `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_URL` with the heroku url? Such as `https://i-workout.herokuapp.com`. Also I'm getting a syntax error

Comment: 2016-12-31T20:13:12.533456+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: /      /app/src/knexfile.js: Unexpected token, expected , (48:0)
    2016-12-31T20:13:12.533457+00:00 app[web.1]:   46 |     }
    2016-12-31T20:13:12.533457+00:00 app[web.1]:   47 | }
    2016-12-31T20:13:12.533458+00:00 app[web.1]: > 48 | 
    2016-12-31T20:13:12.533459+00:00 app[web.1]:      | ^

Comment: you should have an environment variable in your app settings in heroku with your postgresql url. Syntax error is due to a missing comma: `connection: process.env.HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_URL,`

Comment: Have you run your migrations? It seems like your tables are not created.

Comment: I did when I was hosting locally. Do I need to do it again after hosting? How would I go about migrating on the heroku database? Thank you for all the help in advance.

Comment: Yes, your DB was created locally for development and not in production. You could try: `heroku run knex migrate:latest`. You're welcome. I'm glad to help :)

Comment: Btw, here you will find more detailed info: https://medium.com/@HalahSalih/how-to-deploy-an-express-app-to-heroku-with-postgresql-database-using-git-266e100d59ff#.126movtxb

Comment: To be clear I logged on to heroku and put the heroku postgres addon to the app, it didn't already have it.

Comment: @BradleyCravens That's fine and it's the reason why you are getting the error message when trying to query 'workouts' table, because it doesn't exist yet

Comment: Okay so I'm following the tutorial on the website you provided but I'm still unsure on the syntax for the last part of before you run the migrate. Do I have this right? https://github.com/bcravens/WorkoutsServer/blob/master/src/knexfile.js

Comment: You shouldn't set the URL, you should set the name of the variable, for instance, if in your environment vars the name of the variable that contains the url to your postgresql database is DATABASE_URL, you should set `production: process.env.DATABASE_URL` in your file.

Comment: Yes okay you're right. I set it to the env var and ran the migration but get this `ETIMEDOUT: connect ETIMEDOUT 50.19.103.36:5000`

Comment: Fixed that by adding detached but now if I run `heroku logs --app i-workout --dyno run.9749` as directed by heroku I get: `2016-12-31T21:37:56.111172+00:00 heroku[run.9749]: Starting process with command `knex migrate:latest`
2016-12-31T21:37:56.872564+00:00 heroku[run.9749]: State changed from starting to up
2016-12-31T21:37:58.683668+00:00 app[run.9749]: No knexfile found in this directory. Specify a path with --knexfile
2016-12-31T21:37:58.771386+00:00 heroku[run.9749]: State changed from up to complete
2016-12-31T21:37:58.758767+00:00 heroku[run.9749]: Process exited with status 1`

Comment: Do you have your NODE_ENV variable set to 'production' in Heroku? If not, you should add it.

Comment: If you still get error messages you can try to install Knex.js CLI in heroku `heroku run bash` and `npm install knex -g` and you can work directly with Migration CLI: http://knexjs.org/#Migrations

Comment: Added the NODE_ENV env var in heroku and running knex.js CLI I get `Error: There is no pool defined on the current client` from the command `knex migrate:latest --knexfile ./src/knexfile.js --env production`

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you so much! My knexfile was located in a src folder which I forgot about when I ran the migration. Also had to add detached because my port was blocked `heroku run:detached knex migrate:latest --knexfile ./src/knexfile.js`